# PHP Classes function inside function?

Tags: php

I'm self-studying the PHP language. And I'm focused on the latest PHP OOP language.

I search for some "ready-to-install" PHP software and as I scan for some references to search and know, I saw lines of code with a structure like this (can't remember so I'll create my own):

```
$myapp->settings->getValue('openforum');
$myapp->settings->setValue('closeformaintenance', '1');
```

So my question is, how can I reproduce the code above? I don't know what term to use that line of code (objects, I guess?).

Something like this:

```
$newLogin->search($uid)->setLogin($dateToday);
```

Like that. I really need to do that way so I can organize my coding structure. Thanks by the way.

And also for the final question, IS THAT POSSIBLE?

Comment: How is this related to "Flexible URL for PHP"? This is a question on OOP.

Comment: Oops. Let me change the title. Sorry for that.

Comment: This does not posit a lucid, answerable question.

Comment: I would recommend going through the [Create your own framework tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/index.html) at Symfony to see some of the componentized techniques you're trying to learn in action. What you're showing seems to be kinda standard getters and setters on a "settings" object.

Comment: If you are self-studying PHP and focusing on the OO part of it, then maybe you should read something about it first. Then the code becomes pretty clear.

Comment: If you are self studying I suggest to start... self studying http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: so you think guys this is possible to happen?

Comment: By the way guys, I don't know if you are mad about my question, but I appreciate your answers. Thanks by the way. Maybe I should spend 1 year in self-studying PHP OOP. :)

Comment: I suppose, what you want  is `method chaining`

Comment: @u_mulder is that the write term?

Comment: @u_mulder Are you sure you see method chaining? I just see getters and setters on an object available as a property on `$myapp`. Method chaining would look something like `->setValue()->setValue()->getValue()...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you try to achieve is called method chaining. You can get this by the following:

```
<?php
class TestClass {
    private $val = '';

    public function test1($val) {
        $this->val = $val;
        return $this;
    }
    public function test2() {
        echo 'Hello '.$this->val;
    }
}

$test->test1('World')->test2(); // Hello World
```

You have simply to return the instance of the object on the method to allow the method chaining.

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thanks @Sebastian Brosch! Amazing. I'll keep this in my notes. "Method Chaining". It helped me a lot.

Comment: I don't actually see method chaining now that I think about it. The OP is simply injecting a result into a method call on `$myapp`. If anything, `$this->settings` is a reference to another object that you get through `$myapp`, but I don't see this for instance: `$myapp->settings->setValue('a',1)->getValue('b')`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly straight forward way of looking at it, using [dependency injection](http://php-di.org/).

Try it out: https://3v4l.org/iSJgL

Note, the below requires PHP 7 due to the `string` type hint. Remove that and I believe it should work in 5.6 just fine.

```
<?php

$myapp = new MyApp(new SettingsBag([
    'works' => false, 
    'random' => rand(),
]));

var_dump($myapp->settings()->get('random'));

var_dump($myapp->settings()->get('works'));

// Let's change it up...
$myapp->settings()->set('works', true);

// Now it should be true.
var_dump($myapp->settings()->get('works'));
```

These would normally have [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) like `\App` and/or `\App\Configuration`, but I ignore that here so it's easier to follow:

```
class MyApp {

    private $settings_bag = null;

    function __construct(SettingsBag $settings_bag) 
    {
        $this->settings_bag = $settings_bag;
    }

    public function settings()
    {
        return $this->settings_bag;
    }

}

class SettingsBag {

    private $settings = null;

    function __construct(array $settings = [])
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    public function set(string $key, $value)
    {
        return $this->settings[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function get(string $key)
    {
        return $this->settings[$key];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

It's method chaining.

See code below:

```
class T {
    public function test() {
        // do something

        return $this;
    }
}

$x = new T;
$x->test()->test();
```